# How to reverse proxy app in a subdirectory?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I'd like to reverse proxy my application under `server.com/myapp/home`m where `server.com/myapp` is the proxied address and `/home` is an URL handled by my app.

What is the best / recommended solution to do that so that the app will generate proper paths`<img src="/myapp/static/...">`

Which of the two following approaches I should take:
 1. X-Forwarded-Path: I proxy `GET Path=/home` and add an `X-Forwarded-Path: /myapp`
 2. Base_url set in config: I proxy `GET Path=/myapp/home` and set `base_url = server.com/myapp`

Answer (score 1):

The nginx rewrite directive can handle what you are looking for

You server block should look similar to the following snippet

```
server {
    listen 80;

    rewrite ^/myapp/(.*)$ /$1 last;

    location /home {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path myapp;
        proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4;
    }
}
```

Take a look at either of the following for more information

- https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

Comment: Hi Robert! Thanks for answear. I know how to solve it, I just don't know which approach is recommended one.

Comment: I'm afraid I was not explicit enough, sorry!